# Question about taxes on stock in the USA

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax

I bought 1000 of stock A at price of 20. Two hours later, the stock price for A went down to 17, and I bought 1000 more of them, and two hours later, the stock price reached 19, and I sold all 2000 stocks.

Will I be taxed on the profit:
     2000*19 - 1000*17 - 1000*20 = 1000    or some other amount?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your calculation is correct.  $1,000 STCG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your math is correct, but you'll also deduct from your gain any fees/costs associated with making those trades, so unless you made those trades for free, you'll have slightly less than $1,000 in short-term capital gain from this series of transactions.

When selling all shares, it's total proceeds from sale less cost to acquire/sell those shares. The order of buys/sells (FIFO/LIFO) only matters when selling portions of positions.

Comment: Also, if you have other transactions (more exactly, other _dispositions_) in the same year, it is the net totals (gains minus losses) for the year that is subject to tax.